# Creating a secure connection between a desktop app and remote server?

Tags: java, python, security, ssl, encryption

I have a desktop app that needs to communicate with a remote server securely.

1. All data must be encrypted.

   - which also means that the data can no be altered by a third party.
2. No one should be able to resend the same data twice (replay attacks)
3. List item

The server is setup with a restful API, so the desktop client will be making https (get, post, push and delete) calls.

I know that a SSL certificate is not sufficient. There are tools like [mitmProxy](http://mitmproxy.org/) that will resign the certificate and show the attacker plain text.

My question is not concerning the [interworking](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/35471/is-there-any-particular-reason-to-use-diffie-hellman-over-rsa-for-key-exchange) of encryption in general. I would like to know what is a common practice to provide Perfect Forward Secrecy most used in practice in the real world?!

If the server is written in python and clients are written in java, are there tutorials or libraries I can look at?

Comment: I hope you find what you're looking for, but remember that `Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSL sounds *exactly* the solution for this scenario. Your statement regarding man-in-the-middle attacks ignores a critical point - tools such as the one you mention require that the client whose connections are being intercepted has previously been set up to trust the tool's CA certificate (which it uses to authenticate as the server being intercepted). If you are properly authenticating server (and optionally client) certificates, then there should be no issue with man-in-the-middle attacks. Replay attacks by a third-party are similarly prevented by SSL.

Perfect Forward Secrecy is a somewhat separate topic, but again there are PFS mechanisms available in SSL (e.g. using Diffie-Hellman Ephemeral key exchange).

As others have mentioned, recommendations for tutorials/libraries are off-topic for StackOverflow.